# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: javascript, jquery

На сайте в консоли браузера возникает ошибка:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at parseJSON (core.js:121)
at Object.success (core.js:90)
at c (jquery.js:5)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:5)
at k (jquery.js:7)
at XMLHttpRequest.r (jquery.js:7)

parseJSON   @   core.js:121
(anonymous) @   core.js:90
c   @   jquery.js:5
fireWith    @   jquery.js:5
k   @   jquery.js:7
r   @   jquery.js:7
```

### `core.js`:

`parseJSON`:

```
function parseJSON( data, handle ) {
var dataJSON = JSON.parse( data );       <--------

var tpl = dataJSON.tpl;
delete dataJSON.tpl;

getParsedJSON = '';
getParsedJSON = dataJSON;

getParsedHTML = '';
getParsedHTML = Mustache.to_html( tpl , dataJSON );
eval(handle);
}
```

`(anonymous)`:

```
function fillDataTPL( php , exp , handle ) {
$.post( php , exp , function(data){
parseJSON( data, handle );              <--------
});
}
```

`jquery.js` v1.10.2

Comment: `console.log(data);`

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:13

Comment: `$.post( php , exp , function(data){console.log(data);...`

Comment: выводится огромный кусок данных из БД

Comment: @EdgarCooper `$.parseJSON(data)` ?

Comment: @EugenEray куда это вставить?

Comment: Вместо JSON.parse

Comment: @EugenEray `JSON.parse` используется во всех js'ах. Замена результата не принесла